# How to add an Image to plot symbol in core plot

Tags: core-plot

I am using the scatter plot and I need to have images as plot symbol. I am using CPTFILL to fill the image for plotsymbol . However I get a crash in "-(nonnull instancetype)initWithCGImage:(nullable CGImageRef)anImage scale:(CGFloat)newScale" that says "Assertion failure in -[CPTImage initWithCGImage:scale:]".

Here is the code :

```
public func symbol(for plot: CPTScatterPlot, record idx: UInt) -> CPTPlotSymbol? {


        let fillImage   = CPTImage(named: "heart")
        plotSymbol.fill = CPTFill(image: fillImage)

        plot.plotSymbol      = plotSymbol
        return plotSymbol
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see this assertion failure if the app couldn't find the image file. `CPTImage` uses the [`-[UIImage imageNamed:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-imagenamed) method internally.

Make sure that the image is properly compiled into the app bundle. Add the file extension (e.g., `.jpg`) to the image name if it is not `.png`.